# How can I use uconv to convert a list of place names to ASCII?

Tags: icu

I'm trying to 'intelligently' convert place name strings to ASCII. I think what I'm looking for is transliteration. I was able to use the 'uconv' util to get some encouraging results:

Say my input was "Emberá":

```
uconv -x Latin-ASCII input.dat > output.dat
```

The corresponding output would be "Embera" -- exactly what I want. However in some cases, I don't get the expected result, (maybe if the input isn't Latin to begin with?). For example, check this place out (I can't copy and paste the name correctly into this text box) http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=karpos+macedonia&hl=en&ie=UTF8&hnear=Karpo%C5%A1,+Macedonia+(FYROM)&t=m&z=12.

Ideally that would be transliterated into "Karpos" (I think), but if I use that as input for uconv, with the above command, uconv doesn't modify it at all.

So given a list of placenames (here's the list if anyone's curious -- http://www.mediafire.com/file/gb0guu117yp1p26/test.dat), how do I convert them into ASCII?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `-x 'Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII'` 
You could also add `--to-callback escape-unicode -t ascii`  force  everything in the output to ascii, otherwise something like `{U+3045}`.

Note that 'intelligently' is...relative here. You're stripping off a lot of information and going through several layers of translation.  This won't help much, but you can do something like `-x 'el-en;Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII'` if you know that the text is going from, say Greek to English ( that's the el-en), then it can attempt to use langauge specific transliteration.